# Replace lines that matches two patterns

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

Hi i am writing shell script in which i have to replace status O to B by referring two parameters as follows

```
1. trng-linx |  17.2.18. | change status to O to P in project tasklist | O | 1m
2. trng-lvk1 |  17.2.18. | change P to O in project tasklist | O | 1m
```

I want to change the status from `| O |` to `| B |` for the line (in this example, the first line) which matches the patterns `trng-linx` and `17.2.18.`

I tried using this

```
sed -i '/^.*\(17\.2\.18\.\).*/s/O/B/' tasklist.txt
```

but it replaces status of both lines instead of just the first line.

This is my desired output:

```
1. trng-linx |  17.2.18. | change status to O to P in project tasklist | B | 1m
2. trng-lvk1 |  17.2.18. | change P to O in project tasklist | O | 1m
```

Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: You already have the output, don't you?

Comment: No, i have put expected out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 awk -F'|' '{OFS="|"; if ($1 ~ /trng-linx/ && $2 ~ /17\.2\.18\./) $4=" B "}1' tasklist.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

#### GNU sed

```
sed '/trng-linx |  17.2.18. |/s/O\s|/B\ |/' file
```